# Insert many rows into H2 database and then read it into List

Tags: java, prepared-statement, h2

I want to insert some rows into an H2 table and then write it into a List again.

However, I always get in my resultSet the last executed statement.

Furthermore, I always get this error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feld "username" nicht gefunden
>   Column "username" not found [42122-197]

Here is my code:

```
 @Test
 public void testInsertAndReadForList() throws SQLException {
        User userA = new User(null, "UserA", "passwordA");
        User userB = new User(null, "UserB", "passwordB"

        String insertStmt = "INSERT INTO user(username, password) " +
        "VALUES(?, ?)";

       PreparedStatement insertPrepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertStmt, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
       insertPrepStmt.setString(1, userA.getUsername());
       insertPrepStmt.setString(2, userA.getPassword());
       insertPrepStmt.executeUpdate();

       insertPrepStmt.setString(1, userB.getUsername());
       insertPrepStmt.setString(2, userB.getPassword());
       insertPrepStmt.executeUpdate();

       int affectedRows = insertPrepStmt.executeUpdate();
       assertThat(affectedRows).isEqualTo(1);

       ResultSet resultSet = insertPrepStmt.getGeneratedKeys();

       List<User> newResultSet = new ArrayList<>();
       int i = 0;

       while(resultSet.next()) {
           i++;
           newResultSet.add(new User(resultSet.getLong(i), 
           resultSet.getString("username"), resultSet.getString("password")));
       }
   }
```

Maybe, someone can tell me, what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by myself:

```
int counter = 0;

PreparedStatement insertPrepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertStmt, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
insertPrepStmt.setString(1, userA.getUsername());
insertPrepStmt.setString(2, userA.getPassword());
int affectedRows = insertPrepStmt.executeUpdate();
assertThat(affectedRows).isEqualTo(1).isGreaterThan(0);
ResultSet resultSet = insertPrepStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
assertThat(resultSet.next()).isTrue();
counter++;

insertPrepStmt.setString(1, userB.getUsername());
insertPrepStmt.setString(2, userB.getPassword());
affectedRows = insertPrepStmt.executeUpdate();
assertThat(affectedRows).isEqualTo(1).isGreaterThan(0);
resultSet = insertPrepStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
assertThat(resultSet.next()).isTrue();
counter++;

readFromDatabase(resultSet, counter); <!-- and here the reading will be done via counter variable -->
```